# Large whitespace at Springer journal template

Tags: spacing

I just downloaded Springer WWWJ template from http://www.editorialmanager.de/pdf/latex/ and after I compiled, there is a huge whitespace on the right. Whitespace was there even if I use the sample from the template directly, anyone has similar experience?
[image]

Comment: Did you bethink that this could be intended in order to follow the formatting demands for a paper submission?

Comment: I'm not sure I see the issue: you are submitting to a publisher, who will edit and retypeset the content anyway.

Comment: I check out other papers in the same Journal and they utilize the whole page width. Joseph might be right, I thought they might use that space for editing and comment purpose.

Comment: If this is at the submission stage, the formatting requirements may well be different from those for final, accepted articles. Lots of journals in humanities, for example, want double-spacing for initial submission but the final typeset articles which appear in the journal will be single-spaced. I assume this is to allow room for people to comment if they wish and to make it easier for referees to read.

Comment: I understood that, but wouldn't it makes us difficult to estimate the actual pages of the paper?

Comment: why was this question a duplicate as it was asked months ago, while the other one was asked days ago ?